# Contour plot on triangular domain

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have to plot a data file which is in a triangular domain. To make it clearer, my data file possess 3 value, two frequencies `f1` and `f2` with a sum lower or equal to 100 (*i.e.* `f1 + f2 <= 100`) and a metric `m`. My data file is structured as follow:

```
f1    f2    m
0     0     x1
...
0     100   xn
5     0     xn+1
...
100   0     xm
...
100   100   xm+n
```

with a blank line each time `f1` changes. I plot a view map with a colorbox representing the metric `m`. Here is a minimal example:

```
set view map scale 1
set style data pm3d
set pm3d ftriangles
set xrange [0:100]
set yrange [0:100]

splot 'datafile.dat' u 1:2:3
```

Given the following result
[image: Example plot]

To plot the contour plot of this map, I use the following script:

```
set view map scale 1
unset surface
set style data lines
set dgrid3d
set contour both
set xrange [0:100]
set yrange [0:100]
set cntrparam levels auto 23

splot 'datafile.dat' u 1:2:3
```

I got the following image:
[image: contour plot]
As we can see, a part of the contour plot is above the line `f(x)=100-x` which shouldn't happen due to the constraint `f1 + f2 <= 100`.
So, here is my question: is there a way to hide the lines' parts which are above the line `f(x)=100-x` ?